# How to add a container widgets and its properties as a constant in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to make a container and its properties as a constant and use it whenever I want. But initializing it as a constant/final/variable returns errors. Is there a way of doing it so? Here is what I mean:

```
const kContainerDefault = Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  ),
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
    left: kDefaultPadding / 2,
    top: kDefaultPadding / 4,
    bottom: kDefaultPadding / 4,
    right: kDefaultPadding / 2,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use final not const

```
final Widget kContainerDefault = Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  ),
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
    left: kDefaultPadding / 2,
    top: kDefaultPadding / 4,
    bottom: kDefaultPadding / 4,
    right: kDefaultPadding / 2,
  ),
);
```

Comment: How do you call it in your code then? I can't call `kContainerDefault` in main.dart

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make `const` a `Container` as the Constructor of `Container` is not `const` that's why it won't let you do it.

#### From Framework Code:

[image]

So, There are 2 ways to do it:

1. Use `var` keyword
2. Use `final` keyword

```dart
final kDefaultContainer = Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  ),
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
    left: kDefaultPadding / 2,
    top: kDefaultPadding / 4,
    bottom: kDefaultPadding / 4,
    right: kDefaultPadding / 2,
  ),
);
```